# Are beans fully initialized in constructor when using constructor injection with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

When using constructor injection with Spring, is it safe to assume that all passed beans are fully initialized?

In other words, is it possible to do the same things in the constructor as in a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` when using the "classic" `@Autowired` mechanism? Or is it possible that some post-processing is executed on the passed beans after the constructor is called?

Comment: Yes. Why do you ask?

Comment: @smutje what about lazy initialized bean ?

Comment: @JEY Then it is also "fully" initialized in terms of usability compared to field injection.

Comment: @Smutje I was thinking about proxies as JEY. Also, for example when allowing circular references in the project, I assume that Spring needs to inject a "half-ready" bean into the other. So I wasn't sure if there might be edge cases when the constructor-injected bean could be a proxy which, when accessed and thus being forced to being initialized immediately, could cause an exception.

Comment: Yes, you most certainly will get a proxy but the interface remains the same and that's all the injection point containing class should care about. If you as holder of an injection point have to care about "white box" problems, dependecy injection would be totally useless.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of using `@PostConstruct` is that , when you are using setter dependency injection , the constructor cannot be used to fully initialize the object and some initialization needs to be performed after all the setter methods have been called (since dependency needs to be injected).Please note that the annotation `@PostConstruct` is completely removed in java 11 and needs the addition of dependency `javax.annotation-api` for it to work.Also @PostConstruct can be annotated to only one method in a class and it will be executed only once in the bean lifecycle.

But by using constructor injection, we are essentially solving the problem of all the dependencies not yet injected when the constructor is invoked.So if you are using constructor injection you can probably not use `@PostContruct`.

Reference : https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html

Answer (score 1):

it is safe to assume that all dependencies specified as constructor parameters are initalised.   other dependencies are not.